# switch php variables between two files on different servers

Tags: php

Ok , so i have a.php on server #1 and b.php on server #2

let say that a.php contains :

```
<?php
$google = 'www.google.com';
?>
```

and b.php contains :

```
<?php
require('http://[server #1]/a.php');
echo $google;
?>
```

basically that won't work , how to make it work **without editing php.ini** ? :D

Comment: What makes you think that PHP.INI will need to be edited?

Comment: @Mike-W you can set allow_url_include to 1 in php.ini then it'll work but i need another way

Comment: The problem is your web server will be serving an executed version of the script output, the only way is to expose your PHP scripts content via other means (Eg JSON or XML). This is why developers create API's. I think we need to know more to be able to help you try to untangle what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Help us help you. Why do you need to include code that's on a different server? Do you have control of both servers? Is there a reason you don't want to put `a.php` on the same server as `b.php`?

Comment: yes i have control on both servers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using JSON, read the global variables and export them as a JSON string, the extract() is then used on the reciving side to restore the variables into the global scope.

config.php on server A

```
// Define your Variables
$google = 'www.google.com';
$string = 'foobar';
$int = 1;
$bool = true;

// JSON Export
echo json_encode(array_diff_key(get_defined_vars(),array_flip(array('_GET','_POST','_COOKIE','_FILES','_ENV','_REQUEST','_SERVER'))));
```

application.php on server B

```
// JSON Import
extract(json_decode(file_get_contents('http://www.domain.com/config.php'),true));

// Now test your Variables
var_dump($google); // Now the $google variable exists
var_dump($string);
var_dump($int);
var_dump($bool);
```

You can invent your own security mechanism into this code to suit your requirements. I would much prefer you consume a specific list of variables on both the transmit and receive end, this method of using get_defined_vars() and extract() is not ideal, but since you're targeting a specific URL that you're in control of your risk is minimized.

Comment: Warning: json_encode() [function.json-encode]: recursion detected in ../config.php on line 9

Comment: Then figure out where the recursion is happening with a `var_dump(` instead of the `echo json_decode(` and add the index to the exclusion list via `array('_GET','_POST',...)`

Answer (score 1):

You simply can't access the source code of a remote php file on a different server. The best method would be to create an API sort of thing (set up a special key):

```
$secretkey = "stackoverflow";
if(isset($_GET['secretkey']) && $_GET['secretkey'] == $secretkey){
$google = "www.google.com";
//Either if a specific string is requested, then reveal that:
if(isset($_GET['req'])){
$request = $_GET['req'];
//reveal the value of string Google
if($request == "google"){
echo $google;
}
}else{
//Or reveal the whole source code if there is no specific request
show_source(__file__);
}
}else{
die("Access denied.");
}
```

Comment: but what if the variable that i want to call is a random variable , i think that wont work :(

Comment: I made an option for revealing the whole source code. Once you have the whole source code, simply retrieve it into a string, remove "show_source(__file__);" and use "eval" to execute it in your local php file.

Comment: Or you can do what Scuzzy said.